# Should someone tithe unemployment benefits and severance pay?

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity, employment, maaser-tithes, yoreh-deah

I know you're supposed to tithe your after-tax wages as well as gifts of money. However, if a Jew is  receiving one instance of severance pay and is eligible for unemployment benefits, do they  tithe these new streams of money, despite the circumstances?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: @shmosel Does a pauper tithe his tzedaka-received?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can lose your job without becoming a pauper, and you can be a pauper without losing your job.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Please know you can rename your username if you wish to go for something more creative. Great to have you learn with us!